# Error in Quantum Espresso configuration with libxc

Tags: installation, compiler-errors, configuration, physics

Please let me know if there's a better place to ask this question. I'm new to the field and know absolutely nothing.

I'm trying to configure quantum espresso with libxc, and no matter what I do I seem to get the same error: 'configure: error: Could not find required libxc library'. I downloaded the libxc source and followed the installation instructions on this website: https://tddft.org/programs/libxc/. I can't seem to find any errors in the installation but I really have no idea what I'm doing so it's possible.

Configuring quantum espresso with the './configure' command and then making PW, everything works fine and I can use quantum espresso just find without the libxc library. Adding the --with-libxc flag, no matter what I put for --with-libxc-prefix flag, I always get the same error pictured below.

I'm working through ssh on my research group's supercomputer. This is my first time using a unix interface, I know nothing about compilers or anything like that, I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem, I can't seem to find any solutions that work on the quantum espresso forums, and I feel extremely stuck. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One needs to compile both programs with the same compiler. My default was using gfortran for one and ifort for the other.

A good place to ask these kinds of questions is to the mailing list listed here: https://www.quantum-espresso.org/users-forum/